# Undefined error when importing date/time value in calender from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

The purpose of the script is to import data form the google spreadsheet into the google calender.

```
function caltest1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 11;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 4;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[0];  // First column
    var desc = row[1];       // Second column
    var tstart = row[5];
    var tstop = row[6];
    var loc = row[7];
    //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
    cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc});
 }
}
```

the values of column 5 and 6 are;

2-3-2013 17:00:00 
2-3-2013 18:00:00

When launch the debug tool - i get the message tstart = undefined and tstop = undefined

When i remove the time value it works fine...but i want also time values in my calender...How can i fix this?

Thanks..remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `dataRange` as an array of 5 columns so you can't have values > 4 (0 indexed).

Simply increase the size of your `dataRange` to at least 8 columns

Comment: thanks! just started learning google scripts...some ideas for links...thanks again Serge!

Comment: when he thinks that an answer is valid, the asker can accept it so that anyone can easily see the thread is completed.